# Straightedge-and-compass construction of the "kissing circles" for three given circles

Tags: euclidean-geometry, circles, geometric-construction

Let $C_1,C_2,C_3$ be three mutually tangent circles. Call the circle tangent to all of them (that is, intersecting each at one point) and enclosed within the region between them their *kissing circle*. In the figure below, the black circles are $C_{1\dots3}$ and the smaller red circle is their kissing circle.

[image]

> **My question:** Is there a simple construction of the kissing circle, if I know the following?
>
> 1. The intersection points of $C_i$ with $C_j$
> 2. The centers of $C_{1 \dots 3}$

By 'simple construction' I mean *without the explicit use of equations*; only a straightedge and compass.

Of course, if $C_1 \cong C_2 \cong C_3$, this is easy; but in general I'm having trouble constructing kissing circles.

**Edit:** Silly me, I didn't realize Wikipedia's ["Apollonian gasket" entry](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Apollonian_gasket) had a section for its construction. I will leave this question here for someone else to stumble upon in the future.

**Edit:** Actually, the Wikipedia page does not give their construction.

Comment: https://arxiv.org/pdf/1704.08747.pdf

Comment: Note that Wikipedia's ["Descartes' Theorem" entry](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Descartes%27_theorem) gives a companion that gives the centers of the kissing circles on the complex plane. This doesn't directly provide a construction, but it could be helpful in devising one.

Comment: https://www.cut-the-knot.org/Curriculum/Geometry/GeoGebra/CCC_Gergonne.shtml  and  https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Problem_of_Apollonius  and https://arxiv.org/pdf/1704.08747.pdf

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If a non-euclidean construction is allowed:

Locus of center of circles touching two given externally touching circles is a hyperbola.
Centers of the given circles are foci, their commun point is a point on the hyperbola.

This fits perfectly to GeoGebra options.

[image]

For a similar problem with a detailed explanation, refer to [this one.](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2967187/generate-a-circle-centered-on-a-line-and-touching-2-other-circles/2968098#2968098)

---

EDIT

A straightedge-and-compas construction by Eric Eppstein is [available here.](https://www.ics.uci.edu/~eppstein/junkyard/tangencies/apollonian.html)

Comment: But the intersection of hyperbolas is, in general, not constructable since it involves the solution of a quartic.

Comment: I added an Edit to my solution.

Comment: Impressively simple construction. Thanks.

Comment: Not seen in the reference: you do not have to construct all six green lines.  Four of them will do, corresponding to any two of the given circles.  When you identify a tangency point of the outer circle, the center of that circle is known to lie on a line through the tangency point and the center of the corresponding given circle.  Intersecting two such lines defines the center of the outer circle precisely.  The same is true with the inner circle.